# Increase maximum number of outgoing connections for full node

Tags: full-node, peers

If incoming connections are disabled, **Max full-relay connections are 8**: [src/net.h#L64](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net.h#L64) and **Max block-relay-only connections are 2**: [src/net.h#L68](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net.h#L68)

How are these decided and how can a user change these values?

Its mentioned in [doc/reduce-memory.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/reduce-memory.md) that each connection takes up some memory. What if the user is okay with it?

Will changing `MAX_OUTBOUND_FULL_RELAY_CONNECTIONS` to 32 or above help in faster sync? Or `dbcache` and `par` are the only options to improve sync?

I tried changing it to 40 but extra nodes keep disconnecting. I see this line in the logs [src/net_processing.cpp#L4581](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net_processing.cpp#L4581) and not sure if its related to DoS protection or something else.

[image: peers]

Update 1: I commented the if statement here: [src/net_processing.cpp#L4577](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net_processing.cpp#L4577) Compiled successfully and tests passed. I could see more than 15 peers connected but sync almost paused after few minutes and nothing happened. Couldn't find anything useful in logs.

[image: peers-sync]

Comment: Number of connections is not the bottleneck for synchronization speed.

Comment: Can changing number of connections affect IBD? How will it work with 1-2 peers and what will be the change with 20-30 peers. At least the downloading part if not verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: outgoing-full-relay-16]

Issue resolved. I was able to get 16 outgoing full relay connections that are stable using the below changes in code:

Adding below lines in [src/init.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/init.cpp)

```
argsman.AddArg("-maxoutfullrelay=<n>", strprintf("Maintain at most <n> outbound full relay connections to peers (default: %u)", MAX_OUTBOUND_FULL_RELAY_CONNECTIONS), ArgsManager::ALLOW_ANY, OptionsCategory::CONNECTION);

int nMaxOutboundFullRelay;

nMaxOutboundFullRelay = args.GetArg("-maxoutfullrelay", MAX_OUTBOUND_FULL_RELAY_CONNECTIONS);
nMaxOutboundFullRelay = std::max(nMaxOutboundFullRelay, 0);

connOptions.m_max_outbound_full_relay = std::min(nMaxOutboundFullRelay, connOptions.nMaxConnections);
```

And `maxoutfullrelay=16` in `bitcoin.conf`. Tried with 20 as well and it works fine.